# How does the element of the field $F_{p^4}$ look like? Can I say it will look like $ [\theta , a , a^2 ,...., a^{(p^4 -1)} = 1]$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

How does the element of the field $F_{p^4}$ look like?

Can I say it will look like $ [\theta , a , a^2 ,...., a^{(p^4 -1)} = 1]$?

Is there any better way to represent it?

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: $\theta$ is the zero element ..@Ihf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, can say that there is $a \in \mathbb F_{p^4}$ such that 
$ \mathbb F_{p^4} = \{0 , a , a^2 ,...., a^{(p^4 -1)} = 1\}$ because
[every finite multiplicative subgroup of a field is cyclic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic).